# EXCEL 2010 conditional formatting question

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have cells conditionally formatted to turn red if the value is < 7.0  this works fine.  Now I have to add another conditional format to those same cells where the cell will also turn red if the value is > 16.0 ......  I have separate cells containing those boundary values.
I cannot find any examples where this is done.  It makes me wonder if it is at all possible.
Thanks for any help.
-E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a rule highlighting cell values *not between* 7 and 16:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Big Ben that worked, but I need to format an entire column of cells to respond that way.

Comment: Then select the entire range before applying the conditional formatting.